# Как в iframe сделать превью для видео?

Tags: html

А как можно добавить к видео превью? А то не пойму как сделать?

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360">
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
 frameborder="0"/>
</iframe>

>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать  изображение , которое вы хотите использовать в качестве превью. Для этого нужно прописать аргумент  в теге iframe.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
 frameborder="0"
 poster="http://путьу к изображению.jpg">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Не работает такое дело.